# Write an excel formula if a combination values exists for a user

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on writing an excel formula to find if a combination of values exists for a user

I have the following

```
Sheet 1
Username   Value
User1.      V1
User1.      V2
User1.      V3
User2.      V4
User2.      V5
User2.      V1
User2.      V3
User3.      V6

Sheet2
Value1.     Value2
V1.          V3
V6.          V7
V2.          V8
```

Here the *User1* has the first combination *V1* and *V3* so he should be marked selected. Thanks for your assistance.

Still trying to find a formula

Comment: *"should be marked selected"* meaning you want "User1" next to the Value2 column in Sheet2?

Comment: I want to represent for each unique user in sheet 1 if a combination defined in sheet 2 exists. In sheet two values represented in each row is a combination.

Comment: Try a different approach. Check if the user assigned to V1 and V3 is the same: if true, return username, if false return nothing. You may use INDEX and MATCH for this.

Comment: Both user1 and user2 have V1 and V3, would they both be *'marked selected'* (whatever that means). Please show what you expect for output for given example (and where).

Answer (score 1):

I put everything on one sheet:
[image]
In H2:
(Depending on where in the world you are located you might need to change ; to ,)

```
=XLOOKUP($G$2&D2;$A$2:$A$9&$B$2:$B$9;$B$2:$B$9;"")
```

[image]

In I2:

```
=XLOOKUP($G2&E2;$A$2:$A$9&$B$2:$B$9;$B$2:$B$9;"")
```

in J2:

```
=IF(AND(H2<>"";I2<>"");"Selected";"")
```

Comment: Nice solution. I wonder if this is how it's meant though, but that isn't on you. You've got my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Since users only appear in the column A more than once if they've got more than one 'V' Value, you can just have a column that says

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)
=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
=COUNTIF(A:A,A3)
```

and remove the rows where the count is "1"

Comment: This doesn't check for specific combinations.

Comment: True. It answers the question as it was worded, though.